How to deploy the expo part of the Tamagui monorepo?
I want to know the different options on how to deploy the expo part of the monorepo as the README file only contains how to deploy on vercel and the expo docs doesn't account for the monorepo with solito, just pure expo.
I also want to know the things i should watch out for like deploying with routing from solito or installed native dependencies.
https://github.com/tamagui/starter-free
I tried doing an EAS build but when running eas build --profile development --platform android on apps/expo the app throws unmatched routes for the initial auth screens and NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null. This doesn't happen on Expo Go, I already tried reinstalling deps.

The initial auth screens are basically "shared" screens on the packages folder where I use the AsyncStorage native module and import them in the next and expo directories.


My EAS build finishes without any errors in the dashboard but I encounter the errors above when running the installed apk on my device.

The expo doctor just warns me that I need to update certain packages but the warning never goes away even though I updated the packages, expo doctor just keeps throwing warnings on the same packages.
I'm still using expo SDK 51 (I don't want to use 52 yet) and my tamagui version is ^1.114.4.

apps/expo/tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base",
  "include": [
    "app/**/*.ts",
    "app/**/*.tsx",
    ".expo/types/**/*.ts",
    "expo-env.d.ts",
    "declarations.d.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "references": []
}

apps/expo/metro.config.js:
// Learn more https://docs.expo.dev/guides/monorepos
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
/**
 * @type {import('expo/metro-config')}
 */
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config')
const path = require('node:path')

const projectRoot = __dirname
const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(projectRoot, '../..')

const config = getDefaultConfig(projectRoot)

// 1. Watch all files within the monorepo
config.watchFolders = [workspaceRoot]
// 2. Let Metro know where to resolve packages and in what order
config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths = [
  path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules'),
  path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'node_modules'),
]
// 3. Force Metro to resolve (sub)dependencies only from the `nodeModulesPaths`
config.resolver.disableHierarchicalLookup = true

config.transformer = { ...config.transformer, unstable_allowRequireContext: true }
config.transformer.minifierPath = require.resolve('metro-minify-terser')

// Add support for `react-native-svg-transformer`
const { transformer, resolver } = config

config.transformer = {
  ...transformer,
  unstable_allowRequireContext: true,
  minifierPath: require.resolve('metro-minify-terser'),
  babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer/expo'),
}

config.resolver = {
  ...resolver,
  assetExts: resolver.assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== 'svg'),
  sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, 'svg'],
}

module.exports = config

Everything works fine on Expo Go but it doesn't work on an EAS build.
